# I'm having error deriving records using Case When Statement between two specific months using Month(EndofMonth) = 08 and Month (EndOfMonth) = 09?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to derive the records between two specific dates.

I'm having error in the "Case When" statement.

```
SELECT T1.BR,T1.CID
SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN TRNDATE BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 1,(EOMDATE IN MONTH(EOMDATE)=08)) AND (EOMDATE IN MONTH(EOMDATE)=09) THEN TransactionAmount end, 0)) AS SHRAWAN
    FROM 
--Nesting
    (SELECT TRH.BR, TRH.CID, TRH.TRNDATE, SUM(TRH.TRNAMT) AS TransactionAmount FROM T_TRNHIST TRH
            LEFT JOIN T_GLLINK GLL ON GLL.BR = TRH.BR AND TRH.GLCode = GLL.Code AND GLL.CoopRep01 = 'Y' AND GLL.TableID IN ('10','30') AND TRH.AppType+'0' = GLL.TableID
            LEFT JOIN T_GLCONTROL GLC ON GLC.BR = TRH.BR
            LEFT JOIN T_CALENDAR C ON TRH.BR = C.BR
    WHERE GLC.FINYEAR = '2018' /*@Finyear*/ AND TRH.TRNDATE BETWEEN /*@FromDate*/GLC.FinYrStartDate And GLC.FinyrEndDate/*@ToDate*/ AND TRH.APPTYPE IN ('1','3')
            AND (TRH.TRNTYPE BETWEEN '101' AND '159' OR TRH.TrnType BETWEEN '301' AND '359') AND TRH.TrnType%2=1 AND TRH.TrnAmt>0
            GROUP BY TRH.BR, TRH.CID, TRH.TrnDate) T1 --, T_CALENDAR C, T_GLCONTROL G
            WHERE T1.CID = '000003'
                GROUP BY T1.BR, T1.CID
                ORDER BY T1.BR, T1.CID
```

The expected result would be sum of all the amounts deposited between the given parameter dates.

```
TRNDATE BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 1,(EOMDATE IN MONTH(EOMDATE)=08)) AND (EOMDATE IN MONTH(EOMDATE)=09)
```

Comment: "_I'm having error_" so quote it in full in your question, please.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(dd, 1,(EOMDATE IN MONTH(EOMDATE)=08))` Doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: Ya, I think i messed up that part. Actually i was trying to derive the date, which is a day before the EOMdate with Month value "08". So if the Eomdate for month 08 is '06-17-2019' then I was trying to get '06-16-2019'.